# How can I set a separator for a taxonomy field?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

Within my nodes I'm want to display my taxonomy field references with a separator, like this:

```
term1 - term2 - term3
```

what I get as a standard is:

```
term1
term2
term3
```

with display suite I can get:

```
term1 term2 term3
```

I know that I can do this with CSS styling, but is there another solution to add a separator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in Twig.

Place this file in the `templates` folder of your theme (`field-tags` is the field name):

**field--field-tags.html.twig**

```
 <div{{ attributes }}>
    {% for item in items %}
      {% if not loop.last %}
        <span{{ item.attributes }}>{{ item.content }} - </span>
      {% else %}
        <span{{ item.attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</span>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

To add classes use `{{ attributes.addClass() }}` or `{{ item.attributes.addClass() }}`, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/212307/47547