# Adding a class to a <div> in .theme file

Tags: theming, 8

Using Drupal 8 and [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) sub-theme.

I see that classes are being added to my divs in the page template file using the following:

```
<section{{ content_attributes.addClass(content_classes) }}>
```

That's great. But what if I wanted to add additional classes to these div tags. How would I do that...in my .theme file somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### OPTION 1

In your template file, you could find the `set content_classes` and add another class name to the list.

```
{%
  set content_classes = [
    'class-name',
    'class-name-other',
  ]
%}
<section{{ content_attributes.addClass(content_classes) }}>
```

#### OPTION 2

In your **.theme** file

```
function themename_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['content_attributes']['class'][] = 'class-name-other';
}
```

**Note:** This preprocess is for the **html.html.twig** file, you need to use the correct preprocess depending on your template file name.

If it's the **node.html.twig** then use function `themename_preprocess_node(&$variables)`

If it's the **page.html.twig** then use function `themename_preprocess_page(&$variables)`

Comment: In option 2, once this new class gets added in array, then we need to add that class to that particular `div` or `element` in `.tpl.php` Or `twig` file, right? This I am asking just for my understanding/knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: @CodeNext yes that is correct, you would do `<div {{ content_attributes }}> ...... </div>` or some element `<p  {{ content_attributes }}>  ...... </p>`, `<body  {{ content_attributes }}>  ...... </body>`